# Jupyter Notebook from Git Bash Here

Tags: bash, git, jupyter-notebook

I have Git for Windows and want to be able to start Jupyter Notebook in a directory of choosing using File Explorer. If I right click in a directory and select "Git Bash Here," a Bash shell opens. I already added my Anaconda directory (where my Python 3.7 is located) into the user path, and I can verify that Bash sees that in the path by "env|grep PATH". However, when I type "jupyter notebook" from the Bash prompt, it finds the script and it starts to run, but reports an "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

How do I set the Bash environment to start a Jupyter Notebook from the current directory where I have a Bash prompt?

Answer (score 5):

I solve this problem with the command:

```
source "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate"
```

Answer (score 3):

When you install Jupyter via anaconda it isn't added to the system's enviornment variables. Your system doesn't know about Jupyter. Only anaconda does because it is managing your packages and your versions for each project you create.

If you're using bash for windows I would think you'd have to install Jupyter notebooks to windows and add it to your environment variables to be able to see it in any directory.

Edit: Here's a picture of me running Jupyter from my windows command line and from the Anaconda prompt.

[image]

Comment: The Bash environment finds jupyter with no problems. Typing 'jupyter' gives me the same response from Anaconda prompt and from Bash prompt. Same as you show above. It is something else.

Answer (score 3):

In your GitBash prompt type the following command

```sh
. Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
```

assuming you are in your home directory.
This will allow you to run jupyter from GitBash and also use UNIX commands from jupyter.